# How to view Gekko variables/parameters for debug purposes?

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I have a fitting task where I am using GEKKO.

There are a lot of variables, arrays of variables, some variables that must contain arrays, and so on.

I didn't have success with the fitting,
so I need to do step-by-step verification of all parameters that I am providing for GEKKO and all the calculated intermediate values.

Is there a way to print out the values of each variable for debugging purposes?
Or to view the values of the variables in line-by-line execution?

for example, I have an array that is saved like a variable `ro`:

```
phi = model.Intermediate( c * ro) # phase shift
```

where c is some constant defined somewhere above in the model definition.

How can I view the values inside phi that will be used in the next steps?

I need to view/save all the values of all variables/constants/intermediates used during the model creation - before a try to solve. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn up the `DIAGLEVEL` to 2 or higher to produce diagnostic files in the run directory `m.path`.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
c = 2
x = m.Param(3,name='x')
ro = m.Var(value=4,lb=0,ub=10,name='ro')
y = m.Var()
phi = m.Intermediate(c*ro,name='phi')
m.Equation(y==phi**2+x)
m.Maximize(y)
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.options.DIAGLEVEL=2
m.open_folder()
m.solve()
```

Here is a summary of the diagnostic files that are produced:

**Variables, Equations, Jacobian, Lagrange Multipliers, Objective**

- apm_eqn.txt
- apm_jac.txt
- apm_jac_fv.txt
- apm_lam.txt
- apm_lbt.txt
- apm_obj.txt
- apm_obj_grad.txt
- apm_var.txt

**Solver Output and Options**

- APOPT.out
- apopt_current_options.opt

**Model File**

- gk_model0.apm

**Data File**

- gk_model0.csv

**Options Files**

- gk_model0.dbs
- options.json

**Specification File for FV, MV, SV, CV**

- gk_model0.info

**Inputs to the Model**

- dbs_read.rpt
- input_defaults.dbs
- input_gk_model0.dbs
- input_measurements.dbs
- input_overrides.dbs
- measurements.dbs

**Results**

- rto.t0
- results.csv
- results.json
- gk_model0_r_2022y12m04d08h12m28.509s.t0

**Initialization Steps Before Solve**

- rto_1.t0
- rto_2.t0
- rto_3.t0
- rto_3_eqn.txt
- rto_3_eqn_var.txt
- rto_3_var.t0

**Reports After Solve**

- rto_4.t0
- rto_4_eqn.txt
- rto_4_eqn_var.txt
- rto_4_var.t0

The files of interest for you are likely the `rto*` initialization files. The name changes based on the `IMODE` that you run. It is `mpu*` for your application for a Model Parameter Update with `IMODE=2`.